# Random people in different places seeing old broken version of site

Tags: caching, networking

A few months ago, I launched a new version of a site for a client on a new server, with a different IP address. It works fine for 90% of the people, but some people in different geographical locations have been reporting seeing the old (broken) site. No amount of clearing caches on the browser or server side makes any difference. Could it be an ISP (Charter?) is caching the site? The new site is on a WordPress Multi install and uses MaxCDN (I've cleared all these caches several times)

Comment: That may be due to the time DNS servers take to propagate domain changes, I don't know, but I suggest that maybe look towards that direction ? If you can, try to get one of the faulty machines to ping your domain and check if its pointing to your old IP.

Comment: This is off-topic for SO, questions like this are for Server Fault.

Comment: I actually don't think it has anything to do with the server. That's what's so weird about it. The site loads fine for most people, but some are seeing files from the old server, with a different IP address. It seems more like a network or DNS caching issue on other peoples ISPs.